# C# Input string was not in a correct format?

Tags: c#

What is wrong with my code? Here is my code:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("Number : {0} \nFloors:{1} \nStreet \n{ \nName : {2},\nLength : {3}\n}",Number,Floors,Street.Name,Street.Length);
}
```

Comment: What are the types of Number,Floors,Street.Name and Street.Length ?

Comment: Number,Floors and Length  are int Name is string

Comment: Type doesn't matter, since there are no format options anyway.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to escape your curly brackets:

```
"Number : {0} \nFloors:{1} \nStreet \n{{ \nName : {2},\nLength : {3}\n}}"
```

If you need `{` or `}` in the resulting string, you need to escape them as `{{` and `}}`.

Answer (score 8):

With C#6 I'd use string interpolation:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"Number : {Number} \nFloors:{Floors} \nStreet \n{{ \nName : {Street.Name},\nLength : {Street.Length}\n}}";
}
```

Plus: as Manfred Radlwimmer stated, you need to escape the `{` as `{{` and `}` as `}}`.

Answer (score 1):

If not C#6, operate on StringBuilder.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("Number : @number \nFloors:@floors \nStreet \n@streetName : @streetLength\n");
    sb.Replace("@number", Number)
        .Replace("@floors", Floors)
        .Replace("@streetName", Street.Name)
        .Replace("@streetLength", Street.Length);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```